# SafeArea is going out of bounds in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

Changing the preview device solves the issue for a while but just after changing any constraints same thing reoccurs.
Xcode Version 13.3.1
[image: Image showing the issue: SafeArea going out of bound]

Comment: Is it only in preview, or does it also happen when you run the app?

Comment: it is only in preview

Comment: An Xcode bug maybe then?

Comment: Yes, may be Xcode issue. It is causing trouble to layout my views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the issue.
Actually the stack view was causing the issue as i had very high value of spacing. Decreasing it to appropriate small value resolved the issue

[image: Image of root cause]